# how to save favorite items in locale storage device using provider & sqflite database flutter

Tags: flutter, provider, sqflite

hi guys i have problem here, i use provider package to add favorite items in favorite page, is working fine, so when i restart application favorite items is Disappear i want to keep items in locale storage, anyone help me how to solve this problem using sqlite database.

I will be grateful for solving this problem

this is favorite model using provider

```
class FavoriteItem {

   String id;
   String image;
   String title;
   String typeFood;
   String timeFood;
   double price;

   FavoriteItem(this.id, this.image, this.title, this.typeFood, this.timeFood,
      this.price);


}

class Favorite with ChangeNotifier{


  Map<String, FavoriteItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, FavoriteItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items.length;
  }


  void addFavoriteItem(String foodId, String foodImage, String foodTitle, String foodType, String foodTime, double foodPrice){

    if(_items.containsKey(foodId)){

      _items.update(foodId, (existingFavoriteItem) =>

          FavoriteItem(
               DateTime.now().toString(),
               existingFavoriteItem.image,
               existingFavoriteItem.title,
               existingFavoriteItem.typeFood,
               existingFavoriteItem.timeFood,
               existingFavoriteItem.price
          )
      );

    }else {
       _items.putIfAbsent(
          foodId,
              () =>
                  FavoriteItem(

             DateTime.now().toString(),
             foodImage,
             foodTitle,
             foodType,
             foodTime,
             foodPrice,

          ));
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

 

     void removeItem(String id) {
        _items.remove(id);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
    
      void clear() {
        _items = {};
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

this is favorite page

```
class FavoritePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoritePageState createState() => _FavoritePageState();
}

class _FavoritePageState extends State<FavoritePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final favorite = Provider.of<Favorite>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFFAEE),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Your Favorite Foods",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xff544646)
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Tooltip(
                          message: "Delete All",
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Color(0xffFFDB84)
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                          ),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text(
                                      "Do you want delete this food?",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          color: Color(0xff544646),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))
                                    ),
                                    backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFFAEE),
                                    actions: <Widget>[
                                      FlatButton(
                                          onPressed: (){
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            "No",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            ),
                                          )
                                      ),
                                      FlatButton(
                                          onPressed: (){
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                            Provider.of<Favorite>(context, listen: false).clear();
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Yes",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            ),
                                          )
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                              );

                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xffFFDB84),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons_BottomBar.delete,
                                size: 22,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                // If favorite items is empty show image and text " favorite is empty "
                child: favorite.items.isEmpty
                    ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 260,
                        width: 260,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            favorite_empty
                        )),
                    Text(
                      "Favorite is Empty",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )

                // else
                    :ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: favorite.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    FavoriteCardItem(
                      favorite.items.values.toList()[index].id,
                      favorite.items.keys.toList()[index],
                      favorite.items.values.toList()[index].image,
                      favorite.items.values.toList()[index].title,
                      favorite.items.values.toList()[index].typeFood,
                      favorite.items.values.toList()[index].timeFood,
                      favorite.items.values.toList()[index].price,
                    )
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 70,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )

    );
  }
}
```

this is favorite icon when click add favorite to favorite page

```
Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                setState(() {
                                  isPressed = true;
                                });
                                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                  content: Text(
                                    "Item Added to Favorite",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xffFFDB84)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                ));
                               favorite.addFavoriteItem(
                                   loadFood.id,
                                   loadFood.image,
                                   loadFood.title,
                                   loadFood.typeFood,
                                   loadFood.timeFood,
                                   loadFood.price
                               );

                               // await helper.createFavorite(favorite.favoriteItem);

                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    color: Color(0xffFFDB84)
                                ),
                                // active favorite icon when clicked
                                child: (isPressed)
                                    ?Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 20,color: Color(0xffff124d))
                                    :Icon(Icons.favorite_border, size: 20,color: Color(0xffff124d)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

[here is screenshot about favorite page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE7pi.png)

Comment: Show what you have done so far. And did you try saving it to an SQLite database? What problems did you face? Don't ask before trying at all.

Comment: @OMiShah here is my code

Answer (score 0):

You should save the list of ids. Here is how :

```
// Shared preferences : favorites list key
const favoritesKey = "FAVORITES_KEY";
    
// Turn the list of favorites into a list of their id
var ids = <String>[ for(var item in items) item.id ];
    
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
// Save the list
prefs.setStringList(favoritesKey, ids);
    
// Retrieve the list
var ids = prefs.getStringList(favoritesKey);
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but i want ask you where should i write this code

Comment: In your `ChangeNotifier`. Save the list when you change it. Retrieve the list in the default constructor. But you need to figure out how to convert the list of ids to the list of favorites.